# how to insert values from function into graphql mutation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

im writing a resolver that will take all fileds from json array of objects and insert it into db.have 3 fields in schema , userid , text that are being returned in a function called getallmessages. Im trying to insert those 3 values into message table using graphql resolver. However im getting an error saying `Cannot read property 'getallmessages' of undefined {"name":"GraphQLError"}`

here is my mutation

```
  Mutation: {
    addMessage: async (
      _: any,
      { input }: any,
      { user }: any,
      { chatService }: any,
    ): Promise<any> => {
      console.log(input, user);
      console.log(chatService);

      const messages = await chatService.getallmessages(input.podId);

      const podmessage = await MessageModel.query()
       .insert({...messages }) // , userId: user.id })
       .returning('*');


      return podmessage;
   },
 },
```

getallmessages function that returns userid , text and message id

```
  public async getallmessages(podId: string) {
const channel = ChatService.client.channel('messaging', podId);
const messageFilter = { id: { $exists: true } };
const response = await channel.search(messageFilter);
const result = response.results.map((message) => ({
id: message.message.id,
text: message.message.text,
userId: message.message.user?.id,

}));


return result;
}
```

messagemodel

```
import { BaseModel } from '@/db';

import { messageSchema } from './schema/message.schema';

export class MessageModel extends BaseModel {
  public static tableName = 'message';

  public id!: number;
  // public messageid!: number;
  public userId!: number;
  public text!: string;

  public static get jsonSchema() {
    return messageSchema;
  }
}
```

message.graphql

```
type Message {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  userId: Int!
  createdAt: Timestamp!
}

input MessageInput {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  userId: Int!
  podId: Int!
}


extend type Query {
  messages: [Message]!
  message(podId: ID!): Message!
}

extend type Mutation {
  addMessage(input: MessageInput!): Message!
  updateMessage(id: ID!, input: MessageInput!): Message!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `ChatService` into the `context` of a resolver, it's the third parameter, NOT the fourth. See [Root fields & resolvers](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers)

> `context` A value which is provided to every resolver and holds important contextual information like the currently logged in user, or access to a database.